# reactjs - this is not a function error on upgrade

Tags: javascript, function, reactjs, deprecated, typeahead

I am actually updating https://github.com/ezequiel/react-typeahead-component this component to be compatible to react >= 0.14 but while changing the methods I just run into one error:

Exchange `this.getDOMnode` for the reason it is deprecated with `this.findDOMnode` it occurs an error: `Uncaught TypeError: this.findDOMNode is not a function`

So I tried a lot about that React isn't binding `this` automatically in 0.14 to several functions. But it did not really helped me out.

```js
module.exports = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'Aria Status',

  propTypes: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? {} : {
    message: React.PropTypes.string
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    var _this = this;

    _this.setTextContent(_this.props.message).bind(this);
  },

  componentDidUpdate: function() {
    var _this = this;

    _this.setTextContent(_this.props.message).bind(this);
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      React.createElement("span", {
        role: "status",
        "aria-live": "polite",
        style: {
          left: '-9999px',
          position: 'absolute'
        }
      })
    );
  },

  setTextContent: function(textContent) {
    this.findDOMNode().textContent = textContent || '';
  }
});
```

Maybe someone can point me somewhere to go ahead!

Comment: Take a moment to read https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React v 0.14 `findDOMNode` is deprecated you can try use `refs`, like this

```
setTextContent: function(textContent) {
  this.refs.element.textContent = textContent || '';
}
```

or use [`ReactDOM.findDOMNode`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdom.finddomnode)

```
setTextContent: function(textContent) {
  ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).textContent =  textContent || '';
}
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/19554/)